# Visualization using Manipulate - using data from a dataset

Tags: manipulate, dataset, visualization

```
data = Dataset[{<|"userId" -> 5311, 
"Rec" -> 
 "You need to improve in Free Response Question type"|>,<|"userId" -> 5312, 
"Rec" -> 
 "You need to improve in Write Code Question type"|>, <|"userId"-> 5313, 
"Rec" -> 
 "You have a great performance in all question types"|>,<|"userId" -> 5314, 
"Rec" -> 
 "You need to improve in Multiple Choice Question type"|>}]
```

Is there a way to create a manipulate such that the control shows the userId and as I move the control, I see the text corresponding to each userId. Something similar to this:

```
Manipulate[Grid[{{userId}, {"text"}}, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Roboto"}], {{userId, 1}, 1, 5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Code below is not very efficient, but maybe it does what you want.
`Manipulate[Grid[{{data[[Position[data, k][[1, 1]], "userId"]]}, {data[[Position[data, k][[1, 1]], "Rec"]]}},BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Roboto"}],
 {{k, Normal[data[[All, "userId"]][1]], "userID"}, 
  Normal[data[[All, "userId"]]], ControlType -> RadioButton}]`

With your `Dataset` named `data` and a RadioButton control this code yields:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
Manipulate[
  data[SelectFirst[#userId == userId&]]
, {userId, data[All, "userId"] // Normal, Slider}
, ContentSize -> Full
]
```

[image: manipulate]